# Does spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true and @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) have the same effect?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I wonder ,if `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` in `application.yaml` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`on `SpringBootApplication.class` have the same effect? Can anyone explain. thanks ~

Comment: Looks like they are the same. Why are you asking? Did you actually **just try** and notice any difference? Maybe try first and if anything about the result seems strange, qualify your question and explain in more detail.

Comment: By consulting the documentation, I know that their effect is the same, and your answer makes me more sure. Due to the rush to ask, the problem description is relatively brief. I will describe it in more detail next time. Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Actually I did not answer anything, I asked you something. But if my "looks like" makes you sure enough, please be my guest. 